# How to get the class type from a string

Tags: java, oop

So for example, I have an array of strings ,and in one of the array positions I have the string that I get from Coronel.getRep(), and i was wondering if there was anyway to figure out what class it came from, if I could from the String, figure out what class it was, since I have a package with all the pieces from the game Stratego and I fill up the game board with the strings from the getRep() function, but how do I know which piece is in the board at a certain location,since there is only the String I cant access the rank of the piece or is there anyway to do it?

for example getRespectiveClass("C") and it would return the class Coronel.

```
public class Coronel {

    private String nome;
    private int total_pieces;
    private int rank;
    private String rep;

    public Coronel() {
        this.nome = "Coronel";
        this.total_pieces = 2;
        this.rank = 8;
        this.rep = "C";
    }
    public String getRep() {
        return this.rep;
    }
    public int getTotalPieces() {
        return this.total_pieces;
    }


    public String toString() {
        String a = this.rank + " / " + this.nome + " / " + this.total_pieces;
        return a;

    }

}
```

Comment: If you're trying to match an object with a String, you could use a Map of some type, or you could iterate through a collection of the objects of interest, say an ArrayList, and check to see which object holds the String of interest in a particular field. This iteration could be done via a for loop or via streams, and the details will depend on how you collect your objects of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The straight answer to this question is NO. The Coronel & String (rep) are sharing `Aggregation` relationship, so you really can't retrieve the container class information from one of its properties.

The best solution to meet your requirement is instead of storing the `Array of Strings` of Rep, use `Array of Object` of Coronel. And you can override the `toString()` method to return `Rep` property. So your represntation of array is not changing but yes the internals. And when you have access to Coronel object, you can retrieve any property you want like rank, nome etc.